# LayoutTransition disappearing and changing not happening at same time

Tags: android, objectanimator, layouttransition

I have this custom "bottom action bar" here: https://youtu.be/TPi5jtcs2wE, that appears and disappears with certain types of webpages (e.g. article/not article). I set up the outermost `LinearLayout` with `animateLayoutTransition` and made a different `LayoutTransition` object, but I want the bar to disappear at the same time as the webview adjusts its height. To be clear, the bar (relativeLayout) is being set to `View.GONE` and the webView should expand to match parent (due to layout_weight) since the bar is gone, but it's not doing both at the same time. I tried changing `LayoutTransition.setDuration()` and `.setStartDelay()`.

The articleActivity xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container_article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.morningsignout.com.morningsignoff.ArticleActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">
    <app.com.morningsignout.morningsignout.CustomWebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView_article"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="9" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="0"
```

The configuration of the LayoutTransition:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_article);
LayoutTransition customTransition = new LayoutTransition();
customTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
customTransition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING);
customTransition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING);
customTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, showArticleBar);
customTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, hideArticleBar);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 0);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, 0);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGING, 0);
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, showArticleBar.getDuration());
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, hideArticleBar.getDuration());
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, showArticleBar.getDuration());

container.setLayoutTransition(customTransition);
```

hide_action_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:duration="300"
    android:valueFrom="0"
    android:valueTo="?android:attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

show_action_bar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<objectAnimator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:propertyName="translationY"
    android:duration="300"
    android:valueFrom="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:valueTo="0"/>
```

I though the `LayoutTransition.CHANGING` animation would make it work, but no. How do I get the webView's height change and the removal of the bar to occur at the same time? Despite setting durations and start delays to line up, it's not working. I think the issue is that `CHANGING` has to happen after `View.GONE` because of needing to know height after the view is gone. Either that or this is not a `CHANGING` animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out I needed CHANGE_APPEARING and CHANGE_DISAPPEARING to make it smoother, not CHANGING. It's not perfect, but now both animations happen at the same time. I tried the actual top actionbar's hide()/show() functions and I think that this is normal.

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container_article);
LayoutTransition customTransition = new LayoutTransition();
// customTransition.enableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGING);
// customTransition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING);
// customTransition.disableTransitionType(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING);
customTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, showArticleBar);
customTransition.setAnimator(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, hideArticleBar);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, 0);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, 0);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING, 0);
customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, 0);
// customTransition.setStartDelay(LayoutTransition.CHANGING, 0);
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, showArticleBar.getDuration());
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.DISAPPEARING, hideArticleBar.getDuration());
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_APPEARING, showArticleBar.getDuration());
customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.CHANGE_DISAPPEARING, hideArticleBar.getDuration());
// customTransition.setDuration(LayoutTransition.APPEARING, showArticleBar.getDuration());

container.setLayoutTransition(customTransition);
```

This creates an issue where the webview persists the scrollY position though on new webpages, which is wrong (should be at top of page on new pages). I fixed it by containing the webview in a linearLayout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/container_article"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="app.morningsignout.com.morningsignoff.ArticleActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="9">

        <app.com.morningsignout.morningsignout.CustomWebView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/webView_article"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_weight="0"...
```